# Do you have to call RegisterClientScriptInclude in postback?

Tags: asp.net

I need to register a javascript file from code-behind. I am interested to know whether this just needs to be called at the initial page load, or do I have to call it on each postback too ?

```
string clientUrl = ResolveClientUrl("~/Includes/global.js");
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(GetType(), "Global"))
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(GetType(), "Global", clientUrl);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should register it in all postbacks. Checking to see if it is registered already is not really necessary. It will only render one include with the name "Global".

Answer (score 0):

You're already checking the file if it's registered by the if clause. So register it in all postbacks. It doesn't matter.

Comment: but how about from some efficiency perspective, say, I don't want to include the check statement :-)